# How to loop different numbers in Lottery game?

Tags: actionscript-3, random

```
public class Lottery extends Sprite {

    public var text0:TextField, text1:TextField, text2:TextField, text3:TextField, text4:TextField, text5:TextField;
    public var backImage:Sprite, luckyBtn:Sprite, clearBtn:Sprite;
    public var tfFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat;

    public function Lottery()
    {
        setTextFieldFormat();
        loadGUI();
    }

    public function luckyDip(event:MouseEvent):void {
        for (var i:uint = 0; i <= 49; i++) {
            this["text" + i].text = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 49);
        }
    }

    public function resetFields(event:MouseEvent):void {
        for (var i:uint = 0; i <= 49; i++) {
            this["text" + i].text = "";
        }
    }
```

How do I modify this so I can still generate a random sequence, but not repeat any of the entries?

Comment: The normal approach is to make a list with every number then randomly remove them.

Comment: Use a [*shuffle* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) over the numbers. Then take/consume the numbers in sequence. This will ensure a decent distribution and prevent any duplicate choices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a javascript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: (I voted as a duplicate because creating the initial sequence and then consuming the shuffled results are mostly inconsequential task details; there are also AS-specific questions easily found by searching for "actionscript shuffle".)

Answer (score 0):

In the lottery game you have limited numbers of results, for example: 5 numbers from 1-50. All you need is to create list of random unique numbers from 1-N.

```
//How to use, one of the results: 9,40,44,29,4
trace(lotteryGenerator(5));

private function lotteryGenerator(results: uint, maxValue:uint = 50):Array{
    var i: uint, luckyNumber: uint, result: Array = [], added: uint;

    while(added < results){
        luckyNumber = 1 + Math.random() * (maxValue - 1);
        if(result.indexOf(luckyNumber) == -1){
            result.push(luckyNumber);
            added++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm a beginner so couldnt really apply it on my project!

Comment: Copy/Past `lotteryGenerator` funciton to the `Lottery` class and use it. Function returns array of unique numbers.

Comment: Thanks again, but I can't get numbers in the boxes!